# Dagger/Hilt is there a difference in modules if they are abstract classes or interfaces?

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have a question and maybe someone with experience can make things a little more clear for me. I have written `Hilt` modules both as interfaces or as abstract classes. Is there an actual difference between those two? For example, I have changed the following module in `Hilt` on my app and it still working.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class LocalModules {

    @Binds
    @ViewModelScoped
    abstract fun bindTemporaryImageFileFactory(factory: TemporaryImageFileFactoryImpl): TemporaryImageFileFactory

}
```

or

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
interface LocalModules {

    @Binds
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun bindTemporaryImageFileFactory(factory: TemporaryImageFileFactoryImpl): TemporaryImageFileFactory
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between using `interface` or `abstract class` when `@Binds` is used. These `@Module` classes' `@Binds` methods are used by Dagger only to understand which implementation class (`TemporaryImageFileFactoryImpl`) should be linked to the interface (`TemporaryImageFileFactory`).

Using this information, Dagger generates its [own](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/4d9c3585706c89f6ef7ae4c7e329a3b898ea4394/java/dagger/Binds.java#L32) code to link the interface with the implementation. After successful build, in IDE you can see that no matter what you use, the `@Binds` method will show as unused.